# How to get maximum value of newly entered record from database in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get the Maximum value from a table immediately after inserting a new record by using below code.

```
 objDataAccess.CmdText("Insert into Patientdetails(Patient_Name,Patient_Age,Patient_Sex,Patient_RfdDr,LabId,Sample_Rcvd,Sample_Dlvd,AmtToPay,AmtPaid,AmtPending)Values('" + Name + "','" + Age + "'," + sex + ",'" + doctor + "'," + LabId + "," + smprcvd + ",'" + smpdlvrd + "'," + AmtoPay + "," + AmtPaid + ","+AmtPndg+")");

 dtpid = objDataAccess.CmdSelect("Select Max(Patient_Id) from Patientdetails");
```

I am getting previous record Maximum value
if I put breakpoint and check then it is taking exact(newly entered record) value from the table which I had inserted.

how can i get the last inserted value

Comment: And what is objDataAccess object type?

Comment: sounds like you're using in the third-party libraries.

Comment: You could potentially use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for this..

Comment: obviously the answer is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but how in that way because the OP is using the _third-party library_

Comment: MAX ID can create several problems, when there are more then one end users. so to avoid this in feature, do use Scope_Identity()...this has been designed for this use.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Not sure what you meant by `maximum value` though, but assuming that you want to get last inserted records where Patient_Id will be the largest number...

```
Select Patient_Id 
from Patientdetails 
ORDER BY Patient_ID desc Limit 1;
```